# Whats it called when the loading web page adjusts to hide the url box ontop androids when loading

Tags: javascript, android, html

And how its done? I am tryimg to get the url box on top of android browser to disapear when the web page loads, pages that do it like m.untappd.com seem to have the page load first and then the last thing that happens is the slight shift down to hide it - thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hideURLbar()  -I don't just look here